# Linking VB.Net Form to Access Database

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple errors but I am not sure how to fix them. Can I get some guidance please? How do you change the "cm" portion to actually make them declare? Lines 9, 182, 183, 184, 193, 194, 195, 196 and 199.....cm is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. – DANI 5 mins ago   
   
  
Line 9 states that connection is not declared. –

```
Public Class frmCalculator
    Dim addClicked As Boolean = False
    Dim subClicked As Boolean = False
    Dim mulClicked As Boolean = False`enter code here`
    Dim divClicked As Boolean = False
    Dim mathOperator As String

    Private Sub frmCalculator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call connection()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddRb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddRb.Click
        Dim FirstNumber As Double
        Dim SecondNumber As Double
        Dim Result As Double

        If txtFN.Text = "" Or txtSN.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Numbers for first and second number")
        Else
            FirstNumber = txtFN.Text enter code here
            SecondNumber = txtSN.Text
            Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber
            txtResult.Text = Result

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtFN.Text = ""
        txtSN.Text = ""
        txtResult.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddRb.Click

        addClicked = True
        subClicked = False
        mulClicked = False
        divClicked = False
        mathOperator = "+"

        If txtFN.Text = "" Or txtSN.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Numbers for first and second number")
        Else
            txtResult.Text = Val(txtFN.Text) + Val(txtSN.Text)
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    End Sub

    Private Sub SubRb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubRb.Click

        addClicked = False
        subClicked = True
        mulClicked = False
        divClicked = False
        mathOperator = "-"

        If txtFN.Text = "" Or txtSN.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Numbers for first and second number")
        Else
            txtResult.Text = Val(txtFN.Text) - Val(txtSN.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDivide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DivideRb.Click

        addClicked = False
        subClicked = False
        mulClicked = False
        divClicked = True
        mathOperator = "/"

        If txtFN.Text <> "0" Or txtSN.Text <> "0" Then

            txtResult.Text = Val(txtFN.Text) / Val(txtSN.Text)

        Else

            txtResult.Text = "Division by zero"

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MultiplyRb.Click

        addClicked = False
        subClicked = False
        mulClicked = True
        divClicked = False
        mathOperator = "*"

        txtResult.Text = Val(txtFN.Text) * Val(txtSN.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        'Dim numOne As Integer
        'Dim numTwo As Integer
        'Dim answer As Integer

        'numOne = Convert.ToInt32(txtFN.Text)
        'numTwo = Convert.ToInt32(txtSN.Text)
        'If addClicked = True Then
        '    answer = numOne + numTwo
        '    txtResult.Text = numOne.ToString + "+" + numTwo.ToString + "=" + answer.ToString
        'ElseIf subClicked = True Then
        '    answer = numOne - numTwo
        'End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Dim numOne As Double
        Dim numTwo As Double
        Dim answer As Double
        Dim result As String
        Dim m As New MathOp2()

        numOne = Convert.ToDouble(txtFN.Text)
        numTwo = Convert.ToDouble(txtSN.Text)



        If addClicked = True Then
            answer = m.Add(numOne, numTwo)
            result = numOne.ToString + "+" + numTwo.ToString + "=" + answer.ToString
            If lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim lstIndex = lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Remove(lstSavedNumbers.SelectedItem)
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Insert(lstIndex, result)
            Else
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Add(result)

            End If
        ElseIf subClicked = True Then
            answer = m.Subtract(numOne, numTwo)
            result = numOne.ToString + "-" + numTwo.ToString + "=" + answer.ToString
            If lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim lstIndex = lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Remove(lstSavedNumbers.SelectedItem)
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Insert(lstIndex, result)
            Else
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Add(result)

            End If
        ElseIf mulClicked = True Then
            answer = m.Mul(numOne, numTwo)
            result = numOne.ToString + "*" + numTwo.ToString + "=" + answer.ToString
            If lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim lstIndex = lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Remove(lstSavedNumbers.SelectedItem)
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Insert(lstIndex, result)
            Else
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Add(result)
            End If
        ElseIf divClicked = True Then
            answer = numOne / numTwo
            result = numOne.ToString + "/" + numTwo.ToString + "=" + answer.ToString
            If lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim lstIndex = lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Remove(lstSavedNumbers.SelectedItem)
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Insert(lstIndex, result)
            Else
                lstSavedNumbers.Items.Add(result)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Choose an Operation")
        End If

        Try
            cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO MathOp (numOne,operator,numTwo,result) VALUES (@numOne,@operator,@numTwo,@result)"
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@numOne", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, numOne))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@operator", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, mathOperator))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@numTwo", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, numTwo))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@result", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, answer))

                'RUN THE COMMAND'
                cm.Parameters("@numOne").Value = numOne
                cm.Parameters("@operator").Value = mathOperator
                cm.Parameters("@numTwo").Value = numTwo
                cm.Parameters("@result").Value = answer


                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

                Exit Sub
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
        btnClear.PerformClick()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstSavedNumbers_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstSavedNumbers.DoubleClick

        If lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            Return
        End If

        'Get the text of the selected item'
        Dim selectedtext As String = lstSavedNumbers.Items(lstSavedNumbers.SelectedIndex).ToString()
        'Split the item by the operator and the = into an array of strings'
        Dim parts As String() = selectedtext.Split("+"c, "-"c, "*"c, "/"c, "="c)

        If parts.Length > 2 Then
            'Define a variable for each part'
            Dim part1 As String = parts(0).Trim()
            Dim part2 As String = parts(1).Trim()

            txtFN.Text = part1
            txtSN.Text = part2

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtFN_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFN.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The first part of your code seems to be confused or broken, and not formatted properly.  Can you please review, and format accordingly?  What errors are you getting? Where are you getting them?

Comment: Lines 9, 182, 183, 184, 193, 194, 195, 196 and 199.....cm is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Line 9 states that connection is not declared.

Comment: Can you please add that to the question?

Comment: Don't just dump every line of code you have and expect us to trawl through it. Post **ONLY** the relevant code. If you get an error message telling you that something isn't declared then the likely cause is that it isn't declared. You appear to be trying to call a method named `connection` but I can't see any such method. That seems to be a pretty good reason to not be able to call it.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow so I apologize if I wasn't meeting the post requirement. I am also new to vb.net so its not coming as easily. The code I have shown already is with some help from others.